# PHP Populate dropdown menu values from database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am a beginner trying to ouptut the values of dropdown menu from a database. I already automatically generate the values from database but the problem i am having is I want the the value that is being selected to be displayed. 
Ideally im trying to update a Subject which I want to data to be displayed in an HTML page where each item could be updated. What i need is to be able to select the 'position' of the subject that is beeing selected.

Here is my code:

```
<p>Position: 
                  <select name="position">
                  <?php 
                    $sel_subject = get_all_subjects();
                    $subject_count = mysql_num_rows($sel_subject);
                    //$subject_count+1 because we are adding a subject
                    for($count=1; $count <= $subject_count+1; $count++) {
                      echo "<option value=\"{$count}\"";
                      if($sel_subject['position'] == $count) {
                        echo " selected='selected'";
                      }
                      echo ">{$count}</option>";  
                    }
                  ?>
                  </select>
```

Comment: He had more than two lines, it just wasn't marked as "code", so the HTML was being dropped.

Comment: Could you do a `echo $sel_subject['position'];` before the loop and see the values you get?

Comment: Yes i did. it does show the numbers. the only thing that doesnt work is the selected subject position.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help! I just realized where I've made a mistake. I have the function get_all_subjects() which contains an array with a variable named $sel_subject. Instead of using a different name when naming the function using new variable like $subject_set to capture the function get_all_subjects, I still named it $sel_subject which is already contained in the function. That's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be relying on `$count` to be some internal ID that remains static; given that it's just a monotonically advancing integer, this seems like a risky proposition. However, if you're comfortable with that, all you need to do is change the value in the last echo statement to be the subject name instead of $count. I would instead encourage you to use something meaningful to the database - for example, some people create an auto_increment field called `subject_id` and key off of that; others like to use [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)s.

I would also generally suggest using a foreach loop instead of a for loop, as it tends to simplify the code (you don't have to worry about maintaining the counter, or creating fence post errors, etc.) Here's a brief example - I'm guessing a bit at what the actual data is that is available to you, hopefully you can extrapolate it to what you actually have.

```
<p>Position: 
    <select name="position">
<?php 
    $sel_subject = get_all_subjects();
    foreach($sel_subject as $subject_num => $subject) {
        echo '<option value="', $subject_num, '"';
        if ($subject['selected']) {
             echo 'selected="selected"';
        }
        echo '>', $subject['subject_name'], '</option>';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. The real issue is that the form is automatically generated from database where it displays the position of subject like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. In this case, all i need is to be able to select the position of the subject that is selected. Example, if position 2 is selected, the value to be position to be displayed should be 2.